# WPF - treeview - drag and drop and contextmenu issue

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, treeview

I have a TreeView. I set a ContextMenu on the TreeViewItems. When I open the ContextMenu by rightclicking on an item and select another item (while the ContextMenu is open) I expect the just clicked item to get selected without doing anything.
Instead the Framework thinks that I want to drag the item on which the ContextMenu was opened and therefor calls the Drop handler.
How can I solve this problem. Thanks

```
  private void TreeViewPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && !_isDragging)
        {
            var position = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
            if (Math.Abs(position.X - _startPoint.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                Math.Abs(position.Y - _startPoint.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {
                StartDrag();
            }
        }  
    }

    private void TreeViewPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _startPoint = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
    }

    private void TemplateTreeViewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isDragging && (e.Source as TreeView) != null)
        {                
          dragQuestion = e.Data.GetData(typeof(QuestionListItem)) as QuestionListItem;
          dropQuestion = GetItemAtLocation(e.GetPosition(TemplateTreeView));
            if (dragQuestion != null && dropQuestion != null && dragQuestion!=dropQuestion)
            {
                viewModel.MoveQuestion(dragQuestion, dropQuestion);
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
        dragQuestion = null;
    }

    private void StartDrag()
    {
        var temp = TemplateTreeView.SelectedItem as QuestionListItem;
        if(temp == null) return;

        _isDragging = true;
        var data = new DataObject(temp);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(TemplateTreeView, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
        _isDragging = false;
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that in the following statements 
_startPoint = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
var position = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement); 
the sender object is not the same. You want to be sure that you get the coordinates relative to the same object.

Comment: Seems like a good guess Dtex. My DragDropController actually performs e.GetPosition(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow) to avoid any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the code you posted, the StartDrag method should never be called in you scenario. but It is obviously called since you end up with a drop&drop operation. Put a breakpoint there and you should see why it's called.

On a side note, this code

```
_isDragging = true;
var data = new DataObject(temp);
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(TemplateTreeView, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
_isDragging = false;
```

is not safe. You should use a try/finally :

```
_isDragging = true;

try
{
    var data = new DataObject(temp);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(TemplateTreeView, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
finally
{
    _isDragging = false;
}
```

**Edit :**  As Dtex suggested, you could also try to replace your e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement); statements by e.GetPosition(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow)

Comment: Thanks, I refactored my code taking in account your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: in StartDrag method " var temp = TemplateTreeView.SelectedItem as QuestionListItem" I changed with  var temp = GetItemAtLocation(e.GetPosition(TemplateTreeView));

Answer (score 0):

try to check `theContextMenu.IsVisible` before `StartDrag`